# Manga where the main character is isekai'd and has 'creation magic' that can create new magic

Tags: story-identification, manga

This manga is where main character gets isekai'd to a new world. This dying man wants to give him his own magic to make him a successor.

After the man dies the main character used creation magic to move the man's soul into a frog. The manga is in black-and-white and the magic is magic that can create new magic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is *[Ore to Kawazu-san no Isekai Hourouki](https://myanimelist.net/manga/74701/Ore_to_Kawazu-san_no_Isekai_Hourouki)* (AKA *Chronicles of My Adventures in Another World With Kawazu-san*).

> Tarou was an ordinary university student until a strange old magician
> summoned him to another world, upon learning that his magical power is
> 8 million, he uses that abnormally powerful magic to revive the old
> man that caused all this... In the form of a frog. Thus begin the
> strange adventures of a boy with ridiculous magical power and Kawazu,
> the former strongest magician, now revived as a frog.
>
> [image]

Comment: yes this is it
 thank you

Comment: [Always a pleasure](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T3iYzyDQ3hQ)