# Isekai manga where the main character is isekai'd by a otherworld wizard, and has superior mana

Tags: story-identification, manga, magic, isekai

I'm looking for an isekai manga where the main character is brought to another world by a wizard that gives him his "mana", but the MC's mana ends up being way stronger than the wizard's

Comment: Was this black and white? Color? Do you remember the protagonist's hair color?

Comment: Does everyone on this world have "mana", or is it special? Does he have to have "mana" added because he came from Earth, or somewhere else non-magical?

Comment: I remember that the wizard that brought him to the fantasy land have something like 1000 mana units, and the protag (who was a normal man in a normal earth) had 1.000.000 mana units, so in the end he had  1.001.000 mana. The wizard was the strongest of his land and was stunned because a normal guy from a magicless planet had much more mana than him

Answer (score 1):

This is likely *[Ore to Kawazu-san no Isekai Hourouki](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/ore-to-kawazu-san-no-isekai-hourouki)*, also identified [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/268188/102326).

> Tarou was just an ordinary university student until **a strange old magician summoned him to another world**. Upon learning that his newly acquired magical power is 8 million (8 million more powerful than an average magician), he uses his abnormally powerful magic to revive the old man that caused all this... in the form of a frog. Thus begin the strange adventures of a boy with ridiculous magical power and Kawazu, the former strongest magician, now revived as a frog.

The magician summons the protagonist and explains that an ordinary magician has a power of "1", he has a power of "1000", and grants him his power. Once in the other world, he inspects his own status and discovers that, with the magician's power, he now has a total power of 8,001,000.

[image] [image]